# Does Linux uses 4.4 BSD Style routing

Tags: networking

In the example codes of Network Programming Vol1 of Richard Stevens book
in README following line is given

```
 cd ../libroute # only if your system supports 4.4BSD style routing sockets
    make           # only if your system supports 4.4BSD style routing sockets

    cd ../libxti   # only if your system supports XTI
    make           # only if your system supports XTI
```

So does Ubuntu 10.04 I am using 64 bit support

1) 4.4BSD style routing sockets
2) XTI
How can I verify this?

Comment: try both, check which one works. But I'd bet the 4.4BSD interface is supported (albeit highly restrictive). Current kernels use iproute2 - a highly extensive routing system.

Comment: @Hubert, it's not interfacing to the routing system, it's a programming interface for transporting packets between the application and kernel.

Comment: oh, *that's* why I haven't heard about XTI, the "routing" part misguided me. And yes, you're right, the BSD style sockets should be used for networking.

Answer (score 1):

BSD Sockets "won" the programming API race 10 to 15 years ago depending on the OS. You'd have to find some really old *nix software to find something that doesn't support BSD Sockets.

XTI was a system aimed at replacing the Posix API, but was a bit more cumbersome than the BSD sockets. It was most heavily used in Bell Labs System V, and was pulled along into some other OSes which are based on it (Solaris, AIX, etc). BSDs, Linux, and Windows do not support XTI by default.

If you're learning something new, stick with BSD Sockets. It is very widely used, and the "best" generic API thus far.